# 3D meat cuts references?

Tags: meat, beef, pork, lamb, cut-of-meat

I always have trouble reading the diagrams that indicate the cuts of meat. It's hard to tell how deep the cuts go, etc. Are there any 3D diagrams out there?
This [blog entry](http://www.amazingribs.com/recipes/porknography/pork_cuts.html) has a cross section of the pig and shows you the real cuts which is pretty awesome!

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but on the page you linked to, in the "More info" section, there's a link to this University of Nebraska [Porcine Myology page](http://porcine.unl.edu/porcine2005/pages/index.jsp?what=rotation3d) which has some pretty cool visualizations - and there's also [a beef one](http://bovine.unl.edu/bovine3D/eng/nIntro.jsp) They're not labeled with cuts, but you can really see the structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch Alton Brown's show *Good Eats* (Food Network) he frequently uses 3D models to show where various cuts come from. A good example is the episode "[Tender is the Loin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7-_ka3DAuY)", where he uses a model of a steer to show where the loin primal is and then location of the tenderloins.